# Google Sheet App Script Timestamp Condition(s)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, timestamp

This is probably really simple but I'm not able to figure this out.

I have a timestamp script that i copied from this cool [dude](https://yagisanatode.com/2018/02/21/add-the-current-date-to-a-sheet-when-data-is-added-so-that-the-date-does-not-changestatic-google-sheets/)

Now, what I want to do is *only* create a timestamp if a cells in Columns A,B,C are changed or are filled.

```
  /**
    * Creates a Date Stamp if a column is edited.
    */

//CORE VARIABLES
// The column you want to check if something is entered.
var COLUMNTOCHECK = [2,3];
// Where you want the date time stamp offset from the input location. [row, column]
var DATETIMELOCATION = [0,1];
// Sheet you are working on
var SHEETNAME = 'Sheet1'



function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //checks that we're on the correct sheet.
  if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) { 
    var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
    //checks the column to ensure it is on the one we want to cause the date to appear.
    if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK[0,1]) { 
      var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
      dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
  }
}
```

I had assumed that adding on a clause to the if statement with the var indexed would fix this.. with changing COLUMNTOCHECK to [2,3,4,5] and so forth.

```
if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK[0] || selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK[1] )
```

EDIT.

Sorry, my apologies for my bad use of English and unclear request.

What I want is the following.

1. a user will enter data into my spreadsheet.
2. I want to create a timestamp using the script above which only enters the timestamp when multiple cells are changed.

so as an example

John enters sales data into Cells A2, B2 = Timestamp Created.

John enters data into Cells A2 = No Timestamp created.

Hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: What's your question? Also note if you edited column 3, `offset`ting -1 column would have the script changing column index 2...

Comment: my question is "Now, what I want to do is only create a timestamp if a cells in Columns A,B,C are changed or are filled". Is that not clear English? I'll rephrase it if so. I've removed the -1 that was my fault, I was editing the script to see what works.

Comment: Indeed it is clear English, but it's a statement, not a question. What is giving you problems with achieving your goal? What has your research into the specific problems you are encountering revealed? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) to get your range.
2. Use `indexOf()` on the array of `COLUMNTOCHECK` to check if one of the columns you're watching was edited.
3. Loop through `COLUMNTOCHECK` and check the values for each column in the edited row. If each column in that row has a value, then enter the timestamp.

Depending on your requirements, you could simplify and make step 3 run faster. If you're only ever going to check columns A & B, you could simply grab that range once (`editedSheet.getRange(editedRow, 1, 1, 2).getValues()`) and then iterate through the returned array of values.

Note also that I removed the offset and am placing the timestamp in column C. Again, I'm not sure of your requirements, but the implementation you had would have overwritten values in column B for edits made in column A.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var COLUMN_TO_CHECK = [1,2]; // The columns to check if something is entered. (Columns A & B)
  var DATE_TIME_COLUMN = 3; // Where you want the date time stamp (Column C)
  var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1"; // Sheet you are working on

  var editedCell = e.range;
  var editedSheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (editedSheet.getName() === SHEET_NAME) {
    if (COLUMN_TO_CHECK.indexOf(editedCell.getColumn()) != -1) {
      var allFilled = true;
      var editedRow = editedCell.getRow();
      for (var i in COLUMN_TO_CHECK) {
        if (editedSheet.getRange(editedRow, COLUMN_TO_CHECK[i]).getValue() == "") {
          allFilled = false;
        }
      }
      if (allFilled) {
        editedSheet.getRange(editedRow,DATE_TIME_COLUMN).setValue(new Date());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried using the first part of your script, but this isn't giving me the result I want. let me rephrase my Q.

Comment: @Datanovice Please check revised answer

Comment: My sincere apologies forgot to comment and green tick. Thanks for your help!

Comment: was just googling for this script again and came across my own post from many years ago, thanks Diego you are a a true gent.